# Django I need to get the top objects in term of rating

Tags: django, django-views

I would be grateful if you can help me with this request.
I have the following models:

```
class Salon(models.Model):  
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60,unique=True,help_text='Salon Name')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']

    def rating(self):
        x= Rating.objects.filter(salon=self).aggregate(Avg('rating'))
        a=x['rating__avg']
        return a

class Rating(models.Model):
    RATING_CHOICES = (
('1', '1'),
('2', '2'),
('3', '3'),
('4', '4'),
('5', '5'),)
    salon = models.ForeignKey('Salon')
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=RATING_CHOICES)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.rating
    class Meta:
            unique_together = ('salon', 'owner',)
```

and I need to create a view to generate the top 10 salons in term of rating.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Salon.objects.annotate(avg_rating=Avg('rating__rating')).order_by('-avg_rating')[:10]
```

Comment: I rated an object to make it high rated but it's still remaining at the same position.

Comment: Then why did you accept the answer? Wait till it actually works for you! I just edited it, hopefully it will work now.

Comment: I though it was just a rate for you. :)

Comment: Sure. It didn't work at first, because I mindlessly copied part of your `rating` method code. It has the same problem - it does not specify which field on the `Rating` model should be used when calculating the average number. So you should probably fix it as well.

Comment: it seems you are expert in django, can I ask one final question? :)

Comment: If it's directly connected - sure. If not you should probably create another SO question, so anyone can answer.

Comment: its' not, so I will create another question.